# how to find A tight bound to this function $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n-i+1} j^2-1$?

Tags: algorithms, contest-math

how to find A tight bound to this function  $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n-i+1} j^2-1$ ?

i tried the following : $\sum_{i=1}^n (2-i+1)/2 *((n-i+1)^2-1) <=  \sum_{i=1}^n (2-i+1)^3/2 =n*(n^3+1)/2 = O(n^4) $
how can i found a better bound to this ?

Comment: You can [explicitly compute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula) the sum.

Comment: Nope. Consider $i<n/2$, then each term in the outer sum is $\Omega(n^3)$, and there are $n/2$ such $i$, thus the entire sum is $\Omega(n^4)$

Comment: How about if you compute the number, call it $f(n),$ for $1 \leq n \leq 10,$ then edit in a line with the pairs $(n, \; f(n) \; ) \;$ you found. This is the easiest application of the calculus of finite differences, finding the coefficients for a polynomial given the values at several consecutive integer points. My father taught me that when I was about sixth grade. Not hard

Comment: i got this at the end :$ (1/12)*(n^4+4n^3-3n^2-4n) $  is this equal to $O(n^4) $or $Theta(n^4)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that

- $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$
- $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$
- $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$

then compute

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-i+1} j^2-1=\sum_{j=1}^{n-i+1} j^2-\sum_{j=1}^{n-i+1}1$$

and finally

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n-i+1} j^2-1$$

Comment: i actually did this at first , but i got very long equation so i thought i was going the wrong way

Comment: @newprogrammerha Yes indeed tha calculation is maybe quite long but not difficult to perform.

Comment: ok i will countinue this tomorrow lol and i will update what i get as a result

Comment: i got this at the end :$ (1/12)*(n^4+4n^3-3n^2-4n) $  is this equal to $O(n^4) $or $Theta(n^4)$ ?

Comment: yes it is $O(n^4)$

Answer (score 0):

Almost as gimusi answered, consider $$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n-i+1}(j^2-1)$$ Consider, for the time being 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{m}(j^2-1)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}j^2-\sum_{j=1}^{m}1=\frac{1}{6} m (m+1) (2 m+1)-m=\frac{1}{6} (m-1) m (2 m+5)$$ Now, replace $m$ by $(n-i+1)$ and group terms in $i$ to get
$$\frac{1}{6} (m-1) m (2 m+5) =\frac{1}{6} \left(2 n^3+9 n^2+7 n\right)-i \left(n^2+3 n+\frac{7}{6}\right)+i^2
   \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)-\frac{i^3}{3}$$ making
$$S_n=\frac{1}{6} \left(2 n^3+9 n^2+7 n\right)\sum_{i=1}^{n}1-\left(n^2+3 n+\frac{7}{6}\right)\sum_{i=1}^{n}i+\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2-\frac 13\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3 $$ and the summations are already given in gimusi's answer.

Just simplify and get a nice formula for $S_n$..

Comment: i got this at the end :$ (1/12)*(n^4+4n^3-3n^2-4n) $  is this equal to $O(n^4) $or $Theta(n^4)$ ?

Comment: @newprogrammerha. I got $\frac{1}{12} \left(n^4+4 n^3-n^2-4 n\right)$ if no mistake on my side. This is $O(n^4)$ as suspected from the very start.

Comment: yes i i got exactly what you gor i don't know why i put $ -3n^2$ that was by mistake

Comment: whay i can't accept both answers ?

Comment: thank you so much !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!